# Select Dropdown not Updating

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to practice with some D3 and using select dropdowns to change the colors, etc.  So I've been practicing with the Sankey (Parallel Sets example on the D3 website).

There are two buttons - one basically is selecting different columns from the data, and the second button populates the unique values under that column.

Right now, I'm just trying to get the 2nd button to update with the unique value when the first button changes.  I know I'm getting the new unique values but the 2nd button never changes.

https://jsfiddle.net/jimdholland/vrq7mw3g/4/

```
var dataRaw = 'Survived,Sex,Age,Class,value\nPerished,Male,Adult,Crew,670\nPerished,Male,Adult,Third Class,387\nPerished,Male,Adult,Second Class,154\nPerished,Male,Adult,First Class,118\nPerished,Male,Child,Third Class,35\nPerished,Female,Adult,Crew,3\nPerished,Female,Adult,Third Class,89\nPerished,Female,Adult,Second Class,13\nPerished,Female,Adult,First Class,4\nPerished,Female,Child,Third Class,17\nSurvived,Male,Adult,Crew,192\nSurvived,Male,Adult,Third Class,75\nSurvived,Male,Adult,Second Class,14\nSurvived,Male,Adult,First Class,57\nSurvived,Male,Child,Third Class,13\nSurvived,Male,Child,Second Class,11\nSurvived,Male,Child,First Class,5\nSurvived,Female,Adult,Crew,20\nSurvived,Female,Adult,Third Class,76\nSurvived,Female,Adult,Second Class,80\nSurvived,Female,Adult,First Class,140\nSurvived,Female,Child,Third Class,14\nSurvived,Female,Child,Second Class,13\nSurvived,Female,Child,First Class,1'

var data = d3.csvParse(dataRaw);
for (const d of data) {d.value = +d.value; }

var keys = data.columns.slice(0, -1)

let dropDefault = 'Survived'
var subOptions = [...new Set(data.map(d => d[dropDefault]))];

var mainButton = d3.select("#selectButton")
      .selectAll('option')
      .data(keys)
      .enter()
      .append('option')
      .text(function (d) { return d; }) // text showed in the menu
      .attr("value", function (d) { return d; }) // corresponding value returned

// add the options to the button
var subButton = d3.select("#selectButtonAfter")
      .selectAll('option')
      .data(subOptions)
      .enter()
      .append('option')
      .text(function (d) { return d; }) // text showed in the menu
      .attr("value", function (d) { return d; }) // corresponding value returned

// Chart stuff here - see Fiddle below with all of it.


// Second issue, doing mainButton.on("change"...) doesn't work, have to do the select.
d3.select("#selectButton").on("change", function(d){

  var newOption = d3.select(this).property('value');

  console.log(newOption);

  var NewsubOptions = [...new Set(data.map(d => d[newOption]))];

    console.log(NewsubOptions);
    
  d3.select("#selectButtonAfter").data(NewsubOptions)
    .exit()
    .enter()
    .append('option')
    .text(function (d) { return d; }) // text showed in the menu
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d; }) // corresponding value returned


});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

```
d3.select("#selectButtonAfter").data(NewsubOptions)
    .exit()
    .enter()
    .append('option')
    .text(function (d) { return d; }) // text showed in the menu
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d; }) // corresponding value returned
```

Some of them are:

1. you cannot use `data` with `d3.select()`
2. You need to have a key function, otherwise you're binding by index
3. You cannot chain `data`, `exit` and `enter` like you did here.

A conventional approach would be:

```
let select = d3.select("#selectButtonAfter").selectAll("option")
    .data(NewsubOptions, d => d);

select.exit().remove();

const selectEnter = select.enter()
    .append('option');

select = selectEnter.merge(select);

select.text(function(d) {
      return d;
    }) // text showed in the menu
    .attr("value", function(d) {
      return d;
    }) // corresponding value returned
```

It could be even shorter, but the snippet above allows for selects with different number of options.

Here's your code with that change:

```js
var dataRaw = 'Survived,Sex,Age,Class,value\nPerished,Male,Adult,Crew,670\nPerished,Male,Adult,Third Class,387\nPerished,Male,Adult,Second Class,154\nPerished,Male,Adult,First Class,118\nPerished,Male,Child,Third Class,35\nPerished,Female,Adult,Crew,3\nPerished,Female,Adult,Third Class,89\nPerished,Female,Adult,Second Class,13\nPerished,Female,Adult,First Class,4\nPerished,Female,Child,Third Class,17\nSurvived,Male,Adult,Crew,192\nSurvived,Male,Adult,Third Class,75\nSurvived,Male,Adult,Second Class,14\nSurvived,Male,Adult,First Class,57\nSurvived,Male,Child,Third Class,13\nSurvived,Male,Child,Second Class,11\nSurvived,Male,Child,First Class,5\nSurvived,Female,Adult,Crew,20\nSurvived,Female,Adult,Third Class,76\nSurvived,Female,Adult,Second Class,80\nSurvived,Female,Adult,First Class,140\nSurvived,Female,Child,Third Class,14\nSurvived,Female,Child,Second Class,13\nSurvived,Female,Child,First Class,1'

var data = d3.csvParse(dataRaw);
for (const d of data) {
  d.value = +d.value;
}

var keys = data.columns.slice(0, -1)

let dropDefault = 'Survived'
var subOptions = [...new Set(data.map(d => d[dropDefault]))];

var mainButton = d3.select("#selectButton")
  .selectAll('option')
  .data(keys)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  }) // text showed in the menu
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d;
  }) // corresponding value returned

console.log(subOptions);
console.log("Just loaded subs");

// add the options to the button
var subButton = d3.select("#selectButtonAfter")
  .selectAll('option')
  .data(subOptions)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  }) // text showed in the menu
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d;
  }) // corresponding value returned



var width = 975;
var height = 720;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["Perished"], ["#da4f81"]).unknown("#ccc")

var sankey = d3.sankey()
  .nodeSort(null)
  .linkSort(null)
  .nodeWidth(4)
  .nodePadding(20)
  .extent([
    [0, 5],
    [width, height - 5]
  ])

let index = -1;
const nodes = [];
const nodeByKey = new Map;
const indexByKey = new Map;
const links = [];

for (const k of keys) {
  for (const d of data) {
    const key = JSON.stringify([k, d[k]]);
    if (nodeByKey.has(key)) continue;
    const node = {
      name: d[k]
    };
    nodes.push(node);
    nodeByKey.set(key, node);
    indexByKey.set(key, ++index);
  }
};



for (let i = 1; i < keys.length; ++i) {
  const a = keys[i - 1];
  const b = keys[i];
  const prefix = keys.slice(0, i + 1);
  const linkByKey = new Map;
  for (const d of data) {
    const names = prefix.map(k => d[k]);

    const key = JSON.stringify(names);
    const value = d.value || 1;
    let link = linkByKey.get(key);
    if (link) {
      link.value += value;
      continue;
    }
    link = {
      source: indexByKey.get(JSON.stringify([a, d[a]])),
      target: indexByKey.get(JSON.stringify([b, d[b]])),
      names,
      value
    };
    links.push(link);
    linkByKey.set(key, link);
  }
};


let graphData = {
  nodes,
  links
};


const svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);


let g = sankey(graphData);
let gtest = sankey({
  nodes: graphData.nodes.map(d => Object.assign({}, d)),
  links: graphData.links.map(d => Object.assign({}, d))
});

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(g.nodes)
  .join("rect")
  .attr("x", d => d.x0)
  .attr("y", d => d.y0)
  .attr("height", d => d.y1 - d.y0)
  .attr("width", d => d.x1 - d.x0)
  .append("title")
  .text(d => `${d.name}\n${d.value.toLocaleString()}`);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(g.links)
  .join("path")
  .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
  .attr("stroke", d => color(d.names[0]))
  .attr("stroke-width", d => d.width)
  .style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply")
  .append("title")
  .text(d => `${d.names.join(" → ")}\n${d.value.toLocaleString()}`);

svg.append("g")
  .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(g.nodes)
  .join("text")
  .attr("x", d => d.x0 < width / 2 ? d.x1 + 6 : d.x0 - 6)
  .attr("y", d => (d.y1 + d.y0) / 2)
  .attr("dy", "0.35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x0 < width / 2 ? "start" : "end")
  .text(d => d.name)
  .append("tspan")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
  .text(d => ` ${d.value.toLocaleString()}`);


d3.select("#selectButton").on("change", function(d) {

  var newOption = d3.select(this).property('value');

  console.log(newOption);

  var NewsubOptions = [...new Set(data.map(d => d[newOption]))];

  console.log(NewsubOptions);

  let select = d3.select("#selectButtonAfter").selectAll("option")
    .data(NewsubOptions, d => d);

  select.exit().remove();

  const selectEnter = select.enter()
    .append('option');

  select = selectEnter.merge(select);

  select.text(function(d) {
      return d;
    }) // text showed in the menu
    .attr("value", function(d) {
      return d;
    }) // corresponding value returned


});
```

```html
<body>

<!-- Initialize a select button -->
<select id="selectButton"></select>
<select id="selectButtonAfter"></select>

<div id="chart"></div>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-sankey@0"></script>

</body>
```